# Variable product with main price and add variant price to main regular price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible for a Variable product act as a simple product with a regular price and when a variant is selected then the variant price will be added to the main price?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, but instead, you can make a simple product an using plugins like [product addons](https://www.google.com/search?q=Woocommerce+addons) or coding it [with a custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button+field)

Comment: Any idea how would i do that using custom field? any example?

Comment: Please search a bit… There is for example this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806877/override-woocommerce-cart-item-price-with-product-custom-field-value/49807216#49807216

Comment: thank you @LoicTheAztec also do you have example on how to show the option selected in the cart? example text "with giftwrap" ?

Comment: The right hook is `woocommerce_get_item_data` like in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220142/add-a-product-add-on-field-to-specific-products-on-woocommerce/56221304#56221304 …  Also If you can, don't be shy and upvote the answers that are useful to you with moderation of course (no more than 3 to 5 a day for the same user)

Answer (score 0):

Opted to create a product option based on above recommendation